# Neo4j: Null pointer exception

Tags: nullpointerexception, transactions, neo4j, graph-databases

I am working on neo4j to form a graphdatabase out of RDF file. Following is the code:

```
public class neo4j {

private GraphDatabaseService db;

public neo4j(String graphpath) {

        try{
        this.db = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(graphpath);
        registerShutdownHook(db);
        }catch(Exception e){
            File file = new File(graphpath+"/tm_tx_log.1");
            file.delete();
        }

}

private static void registerShutdownHook(final GraphDatabaseService graphDb) {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                graphDb.shutdown();
            }
        });
    }   

public void shutDown() {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Shutting down database ...");
        db.shutdown();
    }

public void clearDb(String graphpath) throws IOException {
    File files = new File(graphpath);
    for(File file : files.listFiles()){
        FileDeleteStrategy.FORCE.delete(file);
    }
    }

public GraphDatabaseService getgdbservice(){
    return this.db;
}

private enum Reltypes implements RelationshipType{
Predicate_of,Subject_of,Object_of;
}

public void graphdbform(GraphDatabaseService graphdb, String rdfpath) {
    jena jenaobject=new jena();
    Node subjectnode = null;
    Node objectnode = null;
    Node predicatenode = null; 
    StmtIterator iter = jena.jena(rdfpath);
    ResourceIterator<Node> nodeindex;
    try (Transaction tx = graphdb.beginTx()) {
        try {
            while ( iter.hasNext() ) {

            /*****The formation of label nodes and relationships******/

           }
            System.out.println();                
        }finally {
        if ( iter != null ) iter.close();
    } 
        tx.success();
    }
}
```

}

and this is my main method:  Edited:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String graphpath="XYZ/data";
    String rdfpath="XYZ/resources/example.ttl";
    neo4j graphdb = new neo4j(graphpath);
    GraphDatabaseService gdb=graphdb.getgdbservice();
    graphdb.graphdbform(gdb, rdfpath);
}
```

The stack trace of the exception, Null pointer

```
            Collected project classpath [/home/enigmatus/NetBeansProjects/KeywordSearch/target/classes]
        dealing with org.apache.jena:jena-core:jar:2.13.0:compile
        dealing with org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile
        dealing with org.apache.jena:jena-iri:jar:1.1.2:compile
        dealing with xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.11.0:compile
        dealing with xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
        dealing with org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.6:compile
        dealing with log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
        dealing with org.neo4j:neo4j:jar:2.2.1:compile
        dealing with org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:jar:2.2.1:compile
        dealing with org.neo4j:neo4j-primitive-collections:jar:2.2.1:compile
        dealing with org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:jar:2.2.1:compile
        dealing with org.neo4j:neo4j-io:jar:2.2.1:compile
        dealing with org.neo4j:neo4j-csv:jar:2.2.1:compile
        dealing with org.neo4j:neo4j-lucene-index:jar:2.2.1:compile
        dealing with org.neo4j:neo4j-graph-algo:jar:2.2.1:compile
        dealing with org.neo4j:neo4j-udc:jar:2.2.1:compile
        dealing with org.neo4j:neo4j-graph-matching:jar:2.2.1:compile
        dealing with org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher:jar:2.2.1:compile
        dealing with org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.10.5:compile
        dealing with org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.10.5:compile
        dealing with org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-1.9:jar:2.0.4:compile
        dealing with org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.0:jar:2.0.4:compile
        dealing with org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.1:jar:2.1.7:compile
        dealing with org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.2:jar:2.2.1:compile
        dealing with org.parboiled:parboiled-scala_2.10:jar:1.1.7:compile
        dealing with org.parboiled:parboiled-core:jar:1.1.7:compile
        dealing with net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:jar:2.3:compile
        dealing with com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:jar:1.4:compile
        dealing with org.neo4j:neo4j-jmx:jar:2.2.1:compile
        dealing with org.neo4j:neo4j-consistency-check:jar:2.2.1:compile
        dealing with org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:1.4.0:compile
        dealing with org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:4.10.2:compile
        dealing with org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:4.10.2:compile
        dealing with org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:jar:4.10.2:compile
        dealing with org.apache.lucene:lucene-memory:jar:4.10.2:compile
        dealing with org.apache.lucene:lucene-highlighter:jar:4.10.2:compile
        dealing with org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:jar:4.10.2:compile
        dealing with org.apache.lucene:lucene-sandbox:jar:4.10.2:compile
        dealing with org.apache.lucene:lucene-suggest:jar:4.10.2:compile
        dealing with org.apache.lucene:lucene-misc:jar:4.10.2:compile
        dealing with org.apache.lucene:lucene-join:jar:4.10.2:compile
        dealing with org.apache.lucene:lucene-grouping:jar:4.10.2:compile
        dealing with org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial:jar:4.10.2:compile
        dealing with com.spatial4j:spatial4j:jar:0.4.1:compile
        dealing with org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.5:compile
        dealing with org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:4.1:compile
        dealing with org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:4.1:compile
        dealing with commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.2:compile
        Toolchains are ignored, 'executable' parameter is set to /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java
        Executing command line: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java -classpath /home/enigmatus/NetBeansProjects/KeywordSearch/target/classes:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/apache/jena/jena-core/2.13.0/jena-core-2.13.0.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.6/slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/apache/jena/jena-iri/1.1.2/jena-iri-1.1.2.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/xerces/xercesImpl/2.11.0/xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.4.01/xml-apis-1.4.01.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.6/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.6.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j/2.2.1/neo4j-2.2.1.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-kernel/2.2.1/neo4j-kernel-2.2.1.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-primitive-collections/2.2.1/neo4j-primitive-collections-2.2.1.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-unsafe/2.2.1/neo4j-unsafe-2.2.1.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-io/2.2.1/neo4j-io-2.2.1.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-csv/2.2.1/neo4j-csv-2.2.1.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-lucene-index/2.2.1/neo4j-lucene-index-2.2.1.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-graph-algo/2.2.1/neo4j-graph-algo-2.2.1.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-udc/2.2.1/neo4j-udc-2.2.1.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-graph-matching/2.2.1/neo4j-graph-matching-2.2.1.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher/2.2.1/neo4j-cypher-2.2.1.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.5/scala-library-2.10.5.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.10.5/scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher-compiler-1.9/2.0.4/neo4j-cypher-compiler-1.9-2.0.4.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.0/2.0.4/neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.0-2.0.4.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.1/2.1.7/neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.1-2.1.7.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.2/2.2.1/neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.2-2.2.1.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/parboiled/parboiled-scala_2.10/1.1.7/parboiled-scala_2.10-1.1.7.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/parboiled/parboiled-core/1.1.7/parboiled-core-1.1.7.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/net/sf/opencsv/opencsv/2.3/opencsv-2.3.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/concurrentlinkedhashmap/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru/1.4/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.4.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-jmx/2.2.1/neo4j-jmx-2.2.1.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-consistency-check/2.2.1/neo4j-consistency-check-2.2.1.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/1.4.0/elasticsearch-1.4.0.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-core/4.10.2/lucene-core-4.10.2.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-analyzers-common/4.10.2/lucene-analyzers-common-4.10.2.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-queries/4.10.2/lucene-queries-4.10.2.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-memory/4.10.2/lucene-memory-4.10.2.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-highlighter/4.10.2/lucene-highlighter-4.10.2.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-queryparser/4.10.2/lucene-queryparser-4.10.2.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-sandbox/4.10.2/lucene-sandbox-4.10.2.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-suggest/4.10.2/lucene-suggest-4.10.2.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-misc/4.10.2/lucene-misc-4.10.2.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-join/4.10.2/lucene-join-4.10.2.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-grouping/4.10.2/lucene-grouping-4.10.2.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-spatial/4.10.2/lucene-spatial-4.10.2.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/com/spatial4j/spatial4j/0.4.1/spatial4j-0.4.1.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/antlr/antlr-runtime/3.5/antlr-runtime-3.5.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/4.1/asm-4.1.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/4.1/asm-commons-4.1.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.2/commons-io-2.2.jar org.dbpedia.keywordsearch.uinterface.uiclass
        /home/enigmatus/GSOC/database5
        log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager).
        log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
        log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
                at org.dbpedia.keywordsearch.importer.neo4j.graphdbform(neo4j.java:73)
                at org.dbpedia.keywordsearch.uinterface.uiclass.main(uiclass.java:38)   Collected project artifacts [org.apache.jena:jena-core:jar:2.13.0:compile, org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile, org.apache.jena:jena iri:jar:1.1.2:compile, xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.11.0:compile, xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile, org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.6:compile, log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile, org.neo4j:neo4j:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.neo4j:neo4j-primitive-collections:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.neo4j:neo4j-io:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.neo4j:neo4j-csv:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.neo4j:neo4j-lucene-index:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.neo4j:neo4j-graph-algo:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.neo4j:neo4j-udc:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.neo4j:neo4j-graph-matching:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.10.5:compile, org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.10.5:compile, org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-1.9:jar:2.0.4:compile, org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.0:jar:2.0.4:compile, org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.1:jar:2.1.7:compile, org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.2:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.parboiled:parboiled-scala_2.10:jar:1.1.7:compile, org.parboiled:parboiled-core:jar:1.1.7:compile, net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:jar:2.3:compile, com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:jar:1.4:compile, org.neo4j:neo4j-jmx:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.neo4j:neo4j-consistency-check:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:1.4.0:compile, org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:4.10.2:compile, org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:4.10.2:compile, org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:jar:4.10.2:compile, org.apache.lucene:lucene-memory:jar:4.10.2:compile, org.apache.lucene:lucene-highlighter:jar:4.10.2:compile, org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:jar:4.10.2:compile, org.apache.lucene:lucene-sandbox:jar:4.10.2:compile, org.apache.lucene:lucene-suggest:jar:4.10.2:compile, org.apache.lucene:lucene-misc:jar:4.10.2:compile, org.apache.lucene:lucene-join:jar:4.10.2:compile, org.apache.lucene:lucene-grouping:jar:4.10.2:compile, org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial:jar:4.10.2:compile, com.spatial4j:spatial4j:jar:0.4.1:compile, org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.5:compile, org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:4.1:compile, org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:4.1:compile, commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.2:compile]
        Collected project classpath [/home/enigmatus/NetBeansProjects/KeywordSearch/target/classes]
        dealing with org.apache.jena:jena-core:jar:2.13.0:compile
        dealing with org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile
        dealing with org.apache.jena:jena-iri:jar:1.1.2:compile
        dealing with xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.11.0:compile
        dealing with xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
        dealing with org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.6:compile
        dealing with log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
        dealing with org.neo4j:neo4j:jar:2.2.1:compile
        dealing with org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:jar:2.2.1:compile
        dealing with org.neo4j:neo4j-primitive-collections:jar:2.2.1:compile
        dealing with org.neo4j:neo4j-unsafe:jar:2.2.1:compile
        dealing with org.neo4j:neo4j-io:jar:2.2.1:compile
        dealing with org.neo4j:neo4j-csv:jar:2.2.1:compile
        dealing with org.neo4j:neo4j-lucene-index:jar:2.2.1:compile
        dealing with org.neo4j:neo4j-graph-algo:jar:2.2.1:compile
        dealing with org.neo4j:neo4j-udc:jar:2.2.1:compile
        dealing with org.neo4j:neo4j-graph-matching:jar:2.2.1:compile
        dealing with org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher:jar:2.2.1:compile
        dealing with org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.10.5:compile
        dealing with org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.10.5:compile
        dealing with org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-1.9:jar:2.0.4:compile
        dealing with org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.0:jar:2.0.4:compile
        dealing with org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.1:jar:2.1.7:compile
        dealing with org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.2:jar:2.2.1:compile
        dealing with org.parboiled:parboiled-scala_2.10:jar:1.1.7:compile
        dealing with org.parboiled:parboiled-core:jar:1.1.7:compile
        dealing with net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:jar:2.3:compile
        dealing with com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:jar:1.4:compile
        dealing with org.neo4j:neo4j-jmx:jar:2.2.1:compile
        dealing with org.neo4j:neo4j-consistency-check:jar:2.2.1:compile
        dealing with org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:1.4.0:compile
        dealing with org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:4.10.2:compile
        dealing with org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:4.10.2:compile
        dealing with org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:jar:4.10.2:compile
        dealing with org.apache.lucene:lucene-memory:jar:4.10.2:compile
        dealing with org.apache.lucene:lucene-highlighter:jar:4.10.2:compile
        dealing with org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:jar:4.10.2:compile
        dealing with org.apache.lucene:lucene-sandbox:jar:4.10.2:compile
        dealing with org.apache.lucene:lucene-suggest:jar:4.10.2:compile
        dealing with org.apache.lucene:lucene-misc:jar:4.10.2:compile
        dealing with org.apache.lucene:lucene-join:jar:4.10.2:compile
        dealing with org.apache.lucene:lucene-grouping:jar:4.10.2:compile
        dealing with org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial:jar:4.10.2:compile
        dealing with com.spatial4j:spatial4j:jar:0.4.1:compile
        dealing with org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.5:compile
        dealing with org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:4.1:compile
        dealing with org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:4.1:compile
        dealing with commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.2:compile
        Toolchains are ignored, 'executable' parameter is set to /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java
        Executing command line: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java -classpath /home/enigmatus/NetBeansProjects/KeywordSearch/target/classes:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/apache/jena/jena-core/2.13.0/jena-core-2.13.0.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.6/slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/apache/jena/jena-iri/1.1.2/jena-iri-1.1.2.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/xerces/xercesImpl/2.11.0/xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.4.01/xml-apis-1.4.01.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.6/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.6.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j/2.2.1/neo4j-2.2.1.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-kernel/2.2.1/neo4j-kernel-2.2.1.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-primitive-collections/2.2.1/neo4j-primitive-collections-2.2.1.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-unsafe/2.2.1/neo4j-unsafe-2.2.1.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-io/2.2.1/neo4j-io-2.2.1.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-csv/2.2.1/neo4j-csv-2.2.1.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-lucene-index/2.2.1/neo4j-lucene-index-2.2.1.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-graph-algo/2.2.1/neo4j-graph-algo-2.2.1.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-udc/2.2.1/neo4j-udc-2.2.1.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-graph-matching/2.2.1/neo4j-graph-matching-2.2.1.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher/2.2.1/neo4j-cypher-2.2.1.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.5/scala-library-2.10.5.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.10.5/scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher-compiler-1.9/2.0.4/neo4j-cypher-compiler-1.9-2.0.4.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.0/2.0.4/neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.0-2.0.4.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.1/2.1.7/neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.1-2.1.7.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.2/2.2.1/neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.2-2.2.1.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/parboiled/parboiled-scala_2.10/1.1.7/parboiled-scala_2.10-1.1.7.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/parboiled/parboiled-core/1.1.7/parboiled-core-1.1.7.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/net/sf/opencsv/opencsv/2.3/opencsv-2.3.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/concurrentlinkedhashmap/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru/1.4/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.4.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-jmx/2.2.1/neo4j-jmx-2.2.1.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-consistency-check/2.2.1/neo4j-consistency-check-2.2.1.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/1.4.0/elasticsearch-1.4.0.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-core/4.10.2/lucene-core-4.10.2.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-analyzers-common/4.10.2/lucene-analyzers-common-4.10.2.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-queries/4.10.2/lucene-queries-4.10.2.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-memory/4.10.2/lucene-memory-4.10.2.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-highlighter/4.10.2/lucene-highlighter-4.10.2.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-queryparser/4.10.2/lucene-queryparser-4.10.2.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-sandbox/4.10.2/lucene-sandbox-4.10.2.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-suggest/4.10.2/lucene-suggest-4.10.2.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-misc/4.10.2/lucene-misc-4.10.2.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-join/4.10.2/lucene-join-4.10.2.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-grouping/4.10.2/lucene-grouping-4.10.2.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-spatial/4.10.2/lucene-spatial-4.10.2.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/com/spatial4j/spatial4j/0.4.1/spatial4j-0.4.1.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/antlr/antlr-runtime/3.5/antlr-runtime-3.5.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/4.1/asm-4.1.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/4.1/asm-commons-4.1.jar:/home/enigmatus/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.2/commons-io-2.2.jar org.dbpedia.keywordsearch.uinterface.uiclass
        /home/enigmatus/GSOC/database5
        log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager).
        log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
        log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.dbpedia.keywordsearch.importer.neo4j.graphdbform(neo4j.java:73)
            at org.dbpedia.keywordsearch.uinterface.uiclass.main(uiclass.java:38)
```

in line

```
try (Transaction tx = graphdb.beginTx())
```

that means my graphdatabase service is not returned. But I am not able to understand how it is possible.
Can anybody explain where I am making the mistake.

Thanks

Aryaman

Comment: You might want to post the full main method.  That line (with the transaction) isn't in main, it's in graphdbform() and the main method you posted is syntactically illegal java, so we're missing some details there.   Also post the full stacktrace, in case the NullPointerException is coming from some place you're not indicating.

Comment: Please post the FULL stacktrace, not just the NullPointerException line.

Comment: @FrobberOfBits sorry I have added now the full stacktrace.